# Printing define name c

Tags: c, printing

```
#define Page 5

void printSystemInfo() {

printf ("%i", Page);
}
```

Thats my code can anyone explain me how to print Page 5 in the console?

For now my console looks like this "5" But I want to have "Page 5"

Thanks for helping !

Comment: @Idos: A macro is not a variable! They are completely different concepts.

Comment: The symbol `Page` doesn't exist at run-time afaik, so it would be impossible to get it. It *may* be possible to stringify it at compile-time, but I'd question why you'd need to know the name of the preprocessor symbol.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Of course there is a symbol "Page". It is just in the pre--processor. (if the C language would even use that term).

Comment: @Olaf At runtime?

Comment: You edited the comment. At run-time, no names exist at all, not just macros.

Comment: Your define replaces all occurences of Page with 5, so your code is really `printf("%i", 5);`

Comment: @Olaf Ya, my swype keyboard auto corrected run-time to compile-time for some bizarre reason.

Comment: What about the documentation of `printf` or what your C book says is unclear? Don't try to learn C by trial&error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a little preprocessor trick. We have the `#` operator, which will convert a symbol into a string.

```
#define _(a)    #a
```

When you call `_(foo)`, it translates it as `"foo"`. So, in your case, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define _(a)    # a
#define PAGE    5

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%s: %i\n", _(PAGE), PAGE);
    return 0;
}
```

What this will do is:

1. We define a macro named `_` that takes one parameter `a`. This macro uses the operator `#` from the preprocessor (called [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/cpp/Stringification.html)). This will case a named passed to the macro to be converted into a string. Example: `_(foo)` gets translated to `"foo"`.
2. In `main`, the `printf()` call is then translated as `printf("%s: %i\n", "PAGE", 5);`. In a stepwise way, when the preprocessor sees the `_(PAGE)` symbol, it translates it as `"PAGE"`.
3. The inner workings of this things is explained in the above link, which I quote (my markings):

> Sometimes you may want to **convert a macro argument into a string constant**. Parameters are not replaced inside string constants, but you can use the ‘#’ preprocessing operator instead. When a macro parameter is used with a leading ‘#’, the preprocessor replaces it with the literal text of the actual argument, converted to a string constant. **Unlike normal parameter replacement, the argument is not macro-expanded first.** This is called stringification.

Comment: Is there any reason why "PAGE" can't be passed in instead? Is it just so the compiler enforces it? (I didn't downvote)

Comment: You are clearly not giving enough fish. How will the OP eat for the day, if there is no free fish? Letting them starve is just cruel. The SO community frowns upon such behavior.

Comment: @byxor What do you mean? Could you elaborate? This never reacher the compiler phase. All gets translated by the preprocessor. You can see how this is passed to the compiler by doing `gcc -E def.c`. If you pass `PAGE` directly to `printf`, the preprocessor will translate it as `5`... so what reaches the compiler is `printf("%s: %i\n", "PAGE", 5);` in this example.

Comment: I assumed the pre-processor was part of the compiler. I was wondering if there was any practical reason not to do `printf("PAGE: %i\n", PAGE);`, but as I was typing I realised that the preprocessor would replace it.

Comment: @byxor No, in your example it won't replace. The preprocessor won't replace names inside string literals. So, you example would end up like `printf("PAGE: %i\n", 5);`.

Comment: Ah okay, so why can't we just write that instead? That's what I was wondering.

Comment: @byxor Seems to me that OP wanted a generic way of getting macro names... maybe some debugging dumping thing... Don't really know...

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. This is very trivial stuff, but please ask if something is unclear.

```
#define Page 5

void printSystemInfo() 
{
  printf((char const[])??<0120,0141,0147,0145,0040,0045,0151,!"bad"??>,Page);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use a macro such as `PRINT(P,a,g,e);`, which can trivially get implemented as `#define PRINT(a,b,c,d) printf((ch%:%:b%:%:r??(??))??< %:a??(0??),%:b??(0??),%:c??(0??),%:d??(0??),0040,0045,0151,!%:a%>,a%:%:b%:%:c%:%:d);`. Or as the third alternative, the version demonstrated in chapter 1 of your beginner-level C programming book.

Comment: Trigraphs, octals, negation and a crap-load of imagination!

Comment: Well.. octals and crap sound familiar :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Trivially, the code uses digraphs instead of the pre-processor concatenation operator, in order to merge pre-processor tokens. Each macro parameter is converted to a string with the # operator, from which we access item 0, with the aid of some trusty trigraphs. This then forms the required format string, including the format specifier, which is conveniently appended as octal escape sequences. The string is null terminated by logical negation of the address of the `a` parameter converted to a string. Finally the macro `Page` is accessed through some macro concatenation.

Comment: I can promise that none of the mentioned language features are present in chapter 1 of mentioned book. Tempted to read it yet?

Comment: @Jimmy589 Compiles just fine. Naturally, you are going to need a C99 compiler for the compound literal. Or otherwise, you could see if chapter 1 of your book has an alternative approach.

Comment: @Lundin Hey, wait. I'm just digesting the trigraphs concept I've never encountered before (in C context) :)

Comment: BTW, have you composed this stuff manually or used some kind of tool?

Comment: I tried Enzo Ferber solution and this works. @Enzo Ferber could you explain this  #define _(a)    # a

Comment: @Jimmy589 The `#` operator is a preprocessor operator that converts a symbol into a string. So, the macro `_(a)` is used to convert the name `PAGE` into a string. When the preprocessor finishes, it will translate the code as `printf("%s: %i\n", "PAGE", 5);`

Comment: For the record: if SO thinks that there are no questions too basic and the community will refuse to close them, then fine. In that case there no answers too advanced either, since any knowledge level is fine. My answer is correct and has been compiled & tested. The question has been sitting there for 1 hour now. Tempted to edit my answer and replace it with the superior macro version...

Comment: @Jimmy589 I added some clarification to my answer. Check it and see if you understand it.

Comment: @Lundin I think if you translated the thing into what the compiler will "see", people would actually not vote down (can't guarantee the vote up). SO will always vote down what they don't understand... It's awesome...

Comment: @EnzoFerber More likely, they down vote it because it is a terrible answer. Or in case the question is fine, it is a fine answer.

Comment: I would just keep this question open for this answer. At least until I fully understand it :)